# react redux-persist with routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, persist

I'm using react with redux-persist and have some trouble that "Rehydrate" event is fired twice if the user goes from /home to /search.

So first the state ist correct in the root. Then I change my searchparameters. After clicking on search I can see that the "Rehydrate" event is activated and it changes the state of the app again.

Any idea what is going wrong and what I can do to fix it?

Here is the code that I'm using

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {compose,createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware  from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import localForage from "localforage";


export const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            promiseMiddleware()),
        autoRehydrate()
    )
);
const persistor = persistStore(store, {storage: localForage});
render(
    <Provider store={store} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thanks and best regards

PS: Attached image of the redux state. As you can see after the search is triggered there is a new persist/Rehydrate event. I'm a bit lucky that still the search finishes after the rehydrate event - but the behavior isn't good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how react-persist works exactly. But I think that you want to add `exact` prop to the route for Home like this:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
```

Otherwise both routes will render, and maybe the double action you see is fired when each of those components render.

Comment: I tried to add the exact prop but it doesn't solve the problem. I attached an image of the react redux state

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation and it seems rehydration action might be fired by `persistStore()` so `autoRehydrate()` might not be needed.

> Auto rehydrate is provided as a convenience. In a large application,
>   or one with atypical reducer composition, auto rehydration may not be
>   convenient. In this case, simply omit autoRehydrate. Rehydration
>   actions will still be fired by persistStore, and can then be handled
>   individually by reducers or using a custom rehydration handler.

So try removing `autoRehydrate()`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I tried to remove autoRehydrate(), the behavior is still the same (only that breaked some components). I suppose that the store saves the state for each route.

Answer (score 0):

rehydration is very second step after create store, anything thing else should be done in rehydration callback.

Its the 3rd param in persiststore func.
persistStore(store, [config, callback])

See if working with rehydration callback can help.